# 'dynamic'-like java annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

I have a pojo that is dependent on annotations. It has predefined fields as well as a Set that contains user provided fields:

```
public class MyPOJO implements Document {

  private String id;
  private LocalString name;
  private LocalString desc;
  private List<Field> fields;

  public MyPOJO(final String id,
                          final LocalString name,
                          final LocalString desc,
                          final List<Field> fields) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.fields = fields;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @Indexed(searchable = false, stored = true)
  public LocalString getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @Indexed(searchable = true)
  public LocalString getDescription() {
    return desc;
  }

  public List<Field> getFields() {
    return fields;
  }

}
```

MyPOJO is a 'generic' object, ie, the developer (or consumer) of MyPOJO has fields that are not predefined in MyPOJO and therefore the developer needs to place these additional fields the in attribute 'fields'. The problem arises from the fact that each object in the Set fields needs to have its own annotations to indicate whether the particular field is either stored or searchable in order to remain consistent with the predefined attributes, such as name.

I can think of two options:

1. For each additional field, the developer will have to create an
   anonymous class implementing the interface Field and inside this
   anonymous class, the developer will declare the applicable
   annotations.
2. the Set 'fields' contains a complex object of fieldname, fieldvalue
   and annotations as shown below. I can't figure out how to invoke the constructor for Field. The below code does not compile but it is intended as pseudo-code to signify what I am trying to do.

   Field myfield1 = new Field("dateofBirth", new Date(), new ArrayList({Index.stored, Index.searchable});
   Field myfield2 = new Field("model", "330i", new ArrayList({Index.stored});

There is no construct to pass annotations as a parameter: new ArrayList({Index.stored}.

```
public class Field  {

  private String name;
  private Object value;
  Collection<Annotation> annotations;

  public Field(final String name, final Object value, Collection<Annotation> annotations;) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
    this.annotations = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(annotations);
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public Object getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

I'm not particularly excited with either option and hoping someone can give me some pointers

Comment: It's not really much of a POJO then is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an extensible object model, I'd say a POJO design is just setting yourself up for extra work as opposed to exposing a metamodel.

That said, what you could do is have clients of the API subclass `MyPOJO`, and annotate the properties they define in their subclasses. You would then use reflection to go through all JavaBeans properties of the objects you're receiving and determine the annotations on the getters - similarly to how JPA works.

Comment: Document interface is that API and myPOJO is the subclassed object that has the fields which the client deems are standard. But the client itself doesn't have all the fields at compile time and needs to provide them at run time from a data model.

Comment: In that case, you're probably stuck with option 2 that you described – implementing a runtime metamodel. Annotations are a compile-time feature, I don't think there's a convenient way of using them otherwise.

Comment: thank you. I tried option 2 but I don't know how to pass a list of Annotations as shown in the updated Question above. Any idea?

Comment: Annotations are also regular Java interfaces - for the ones retained at runtime, I'm guessing Java generates an implementing class on the fly. If you want to reuse the annotation interface, you have to make your own implementation of the annotation interface that lets you specify the parameter values in a constructor / using setters / however, and returns them for the methods declared in the annotation.